# Problem passing parameters to WebService asp-net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications

Hi everyone let me explain this issue:

Background:

- I have two web applications
- The first one exposes some web services (server_wapp).
- The second one consumes them (client_wapp).
- I added a new web service to the server application that takes two strings as parameters, and it work OK using it directly form the .asmx page (new_ws).

Problem:

When I call the new_ws from the client_wapp all the parameters have their right content, but when the method is executed in the server_wapp, one of its parameters is passed as null.

Somthing link this:

In client_wapp I have server_wapp.new_ws("string1", "string2") and it gets executed in server_wapp as new_ws("string1", null).

I already rebuilt both web applications, but the problem remains.

Any ideas/comments?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked if both ends use the same name for that parameter (maybe just casing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the link to server_wapp so that the proxy source code will be re-generated. WebService is usually used by adding reference to webservice url, and everytime you do some modifications in the webservice, its should be updated.